# No SSL information on cURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl

actually i having problem to run curl in web server. it does not return anything and keep the page blank. if i run on localhost everything works fine.

and i try to compared the curl lib in localhost and web server. i found out in localhost there are additional information on ssl but not on web server. how can i solve this issue?

does reinstall curl lib is the right way? or how can i enabled ssl on web server

[image]

Comment: i guess openssl is not installed on your server? and when you say "it does not return anything", what exactly did the curl call return? find out with var_dump(), furthermore, if the return indicate an error, what does curl_error($ch) say?

Comment: and what OS are you using? the procedure to install ssl vary from OS to OS, and even between different linux distros

Comment: the libcurl you show there *has* SSL support, powered by NSS. It is a fairly old libcurl though so I would presume you won't be able to speak modern TLS versions with that.

Comment: @hanshenrik the openssl is already install in server.